# how to improve performance of 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

I have a low-level function that will be called millions of times, so it should be very efficient. When I use "gprof" in Linux, I found that a part of the code takes 60% of the total computation of the function (the rest part is to solve the roots of a cubic equation). Here Point is a data structure has x and v, which will be converted to a matrix for later use. The idea is to subtract each row by the first row. The code shows like below

```
    double x[4][3] = {0}, v[4][3] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            v[i][j] = Point[i]->v[j];
            x[i][j] = Point[i]->x[j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
            v[i][j] = v[0][j] - v[i][j];
            x[i][j] = x[0][j] - x[i][j];
        }
    }
```

Can anyone show me the problem of this code? Why it performs so badly?

Comment: If your code works, but could use improvement, it's off topic here. Please post it on Code Review.

Comment: Did you let the compiler do its best by setting optimisation level 3 or similar?

Comment: What exactly is `Point`?

Comment: You're initialising those arrays (`x` and `v`) three times, each time overwriting the whole range (with the exception of the first row, which you initialise twice) with completely new values independent of the previous entry. Then ask yourself if you really need these local copies, can you not simply use `Point[i]->v[j] - Point[0]->v[j]` whenever `i > 0`? Thus saving on all the copies in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I didn't use compiler optimization because I want to improve the performance by myself. I found that the problem comes from the for loop. If I manually assign the value without using the for loop, the perform becomes much better. It only takes 20% of the total computational time. I am a little confused about this problem.

Comment: @ZhengGao: "I didn't use compiler optimization because I want to improve the performance by myself." That is absolutely not how it works.  You cannot achieve excellent performance by tweaking the source code.  You must enable compiler optimization.  This is the very first step.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: not all working code questions are off-topic. This is fine here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in one pass:

```
double x[4][3] = {
    { Point[0]->x[0], Point[0]->x[1], Point[0]->x[2] }
};
double v[4][3] = {
    { Point[0]->v[0], Point[0]->v[1], Point[0]->v[2] }
};

for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        x[i][j] = x[0][j] - Point[i]->x[j];
        v[i][j] = v[0][j] - Point[i]->v[j];
    }
}
```

You could even take that to the next level and put the entire thing into the initializers for `x` and `v`.

Or, if `x` and `v` in `Point` are each contiguous arrays:

```
double x[4][3], v[4][3]; // no init

// fill entire arrays
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    memcpy(x[0], Point[0]->x, sizeof(x[0]));
    memcpy(v[0], Point[0]->v, sizeof(v[0]));
}

for (int i = 1; i < 4; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
        x[i][j] -= Point[i]->x[j];
        v[i][j] -= Point[i]->v[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified as you suggested, but this didn't solve the problem. It's interesting to see that  "memcpy" function even takes more time than manually assigning the values. Unrolling the double loop also gives some improvements on the performance. Of cause, this will sacrifice the readability.